# how to set the simplecursoradapter to a listview in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

i have to set the simpleCursorAdapter into a listView.

how can i achieve that?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is a bit vague, so I'm tempted to answer simply:

```
my_list_view.setAdapter(my_cursor_adapter);
```

But there are better explanations and examples in the documentation. Here is one:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List2.html

Comment: hey thanks for reply. but my activity is not a listactivity. i want to set into tab content how to do that???

Comment: ListActivity is just a fancy activity with some utilities for lists. Not too much there, really. 

To set the adapter in other Activity types, you get the ListView using getViewById() and then call setAdapter() on it.

Answer (score 2):

**ListView** has the method declard as:

```
public void setAdapter (ListAdapter adapter)
```

And the documentation for **ListAdapter** lists **SimpleCursorAdapter** as one of its own indirect subclasses. So to set your **SimpleCurseAdapter** into a **ListView**, you just need call **setAdapter** on the view with your adapter.

Comment: hey thanks for reply. but my activity is not a listactivity. i want to set into tab content how to do that???