# How to polulate a listview using the SimpleCursorAdapter in android?

Tags: android

I am developing a small application. I hav a listview in it. I want populate the listview from the database using the SimpleCursorAdapter. please help me out in doing this. As I am new to android please provide with some codes if possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As posted by moraes: 
[how to set the simplecursoradapter to a listview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264986/how-to-set-the-simplecursoradapter-to-a-listview-in-android)

Direct link:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List2.html